# Google Cloud SQL - create failover failed

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'd created a Cloud SQL server for development without failover at the start.

Several days ago, I tried to create failover replica for it, and the operation had been waiting for completion whole day without further notification.

I think I should try it again today, and I cannot create it. The system is always responding with:

> Could not complete the operation.

I'd changed the name or any random name for instance ID. The result is still the same.

Does anyone have such kind experience? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you choose zone?
When you create a failover, the "location" field will be auto-filled in the edit page. But the "zone" field is empty, you need to select one from the drop-down list.

Just encountered the same problem as you. And it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a pity that I'd closed my old project and start a new one for production, and I could not try that myself. BTW, it's a good reference to others if anyone meet the same problem. :)